# PHP POST form not returning input?

Tags: php

I have about driven myself crazy trying to figure this out.  I know this should be working:

```
//form.php
<form action='post.php' method='POST'>
<input type='text' id='icecream' name='icecream' maxlength=15 **/>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

This is inside of a HTML template, mind you.

```
//post.php 
$icecream = preg_replace('#[^a-Z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["icecream"]);
echo $icecream;
```

And this page should simply display the data reformated but instead doesn't display anything at all.  I'm so lost, I'm going to try rewritting the template again but I have absolutely no idea how that could have anything to do with this not working!

Comment: What is with this `**/>` at the end of the input line? Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to your php file to report errors

Comment: what do you see in the document inspector under the network tab and do you see any errors in console or php error log?

Comment: @PatrickMurphy That's to stop browser caching

Comment: Have you just tried echoing $_POST['icecream']? before the regex?  https://regex101.com/ says you have an error (out of order) with the `a-Z` as it should be `A-z`  full valid regex `#[^A-z0-9]#i`

Comment: Try replacing the `[ ... ]` in regex to `( ... )`, just a thought.

Comment: Debug like var_dump($_POST);

Comment: Oh man, you are replacing values to empty

Comment: @PatrickMurphy that didn't seem to return anything.

Comment: Yeah that regex matches `#*#i' or any other non letter or number character between the ##'s is this intentional?

Comment: It shows it inside the array, so why isn't it working when I echo it...

Comment: Change the RegEx from: `a-Z` to `A-z`

Comment: @PatrickMurphy Yes, it is meant to white list only a-Z and 0-9 characters.

Comment: @BizzyBob that worked, thank you... I swear I copied and pasted this from another form, this is quite embarresing

Comment: Glad it worked for you..! After reviewing the comment chain, Looks like @PatrickMurphy beat me by 9 minutes.. :-)

Comment: @BizzyBob is this safe for database input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code from

```
$icecream = preg_replace('#[^a-Z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["icecream"]);
echo $icecream;
```

to

```
$icecream = preg_replace('#[^A-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["icecream"]);
echo $icecream;
```